# Why standard deviation of same data is non-zero?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to find the standard deviation of few matrices (element-wise). But I was getting some wrong answers. So I tried to check if there is some bug by using the same matrix to get a zero std deviation. But this code is returning some stray values rather than zero matrix. I am not able to understand the cause of the bug. Can anyone help me with this?

I have tried to get the std deviation for the same matrix. In which case I would have gotten a zero matrix. I have tried to print out some values at different part of the program. First part of program works out to be fine. But the part where I try to find std dev, I am getting numbers I cannot understand.

```
from math import *
import numpy as np

for i in range(0,10):
    filename = 'W_10_10_%d' %(1); #using the same matrix
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        l = [[float(num) for num in line.split()] for line in f];
    if (i==0):
        l1 = np.array(l);   
    else :
        l1 = l1 + np.array(l);

l1 = l1/long(10.0) #averaging the matrix

for i in range(0,10):
    filename = 'W_10_10_%d'  %(1);
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        l = [[float(num) for num in line.split()] for line in f];
    if (i==0):
        l2 = (l1-np.array(l))**2; #here I am getting non-zero number
    else :
        l2 = l2 + (l1-np.array(l))**2;

l2 = np.sqrt(l2/long(9.0))

f = open('w_stddev_10','w+')

x, y = l2.shape

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        f.write("%e   " % l2[i][j])
    f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

I should be getting zero matrix as output but rather I am getting some large numbers.

Comment: Hi,
Please provide a minimal example of data that still results in this error (like a 3-by-3 matrix that still has this error).

Comment: Also, it's not entirely clear what do you mean by "element-wise" std (row-wise? column-wise? entire matrix?), so an example with a desired output could also help.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin, by 'element-wise' I meant that I am finding out standard deviations of element of matrices. For example, say I have 10 (3,3) matrices. I sum them all, and divide them by 10 to get the average. Similarly I calculate the std deviation. This problem I only there for large float matrices where data is in scientific format.

Comment: So, you can say you have a 3-d array, and you want to take the std across the 3rd dimension?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin No. I have a 2D array of dimension 3*3 (row*column). I have 10 of such arrays.

Comment: I may have missed something here - do you say that your problem is only there for large float matrices? For a bunch (say 10) of small (say (3,3)) matrices, you do not encounter this problem?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin  Yes, exactly. You see, for the line of code, `l2 = (l1-np.array(l))**2` I'm not getting zero. I am using same matrix to calculate the average. In that case I must get zero standard deviation. I am getting it right for any other matrix. Just the data matrix I am getting in my simulations, is giving me this problem. I have data values as large as e^+24. Can it be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

(Following our discussion in comments)

If the problem appears for larger data but not for smaller data, it has to be a numeric issue, i.e. floating point or something similar. If it is possible to hold all of your data in memory (like making an actual 3D array out of it), do so and calculate the `std` on the 3rd dimension.